# How to make POST with TS?

Tags: angular, typescript, post

i'm new in angular 9. Trying to do post request and get TS trouble with headers my post request - `Unnecessarily quoted property 'Authorization' found`. What its mean? What he wants from me? How can i fix it?

**serviceName.service.ts:**

```
export class DadataSuggestService {
   url = 'https://cleaner.dadata.ru/api/v1/clean/name';
   token = 'f6bf5c998d0e4fcd58cea3b241763e01fe918127';
   secret = 'c6461196cb75f4f880b07f9bf5fb58b7a715b245';
    query = 'Срегей владимерович иванов';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
  options: {} = {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Token ' + this.token,
      'X-Secret': this.secret
    },
    body: JSON.stringify([query])
  };

  takeSuggestion(URL: string, options: object): any {
    return this.http.post(URL, options)
      .pipe(
        tap(
          data => console.log(data),
          error => console.log(error)
        )
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly provide the `method` when calling the `post` function directly. You could try the following to send the headers

```js
takeSuggestion(URL: string): any {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Token ' + this.token,
    'X-Secret': this.secret
  });
  const options = { headers };
  const body = JSON.stringify([query]);

  return this.http.post(URL, body, options).pipe(
    tap(
      data => console.log(data),
      error => console.log(error)
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use an http interceptor which will intercept your http post and add the token to your request. If not try something like below.

```js
var header = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Authorization',  `Basic ${AuthService.getToken()}`)
}

this.http.post(url, header)
```